# Java Multi-Thread racing simulation issue

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, thread-sleep, thread-synchronization

I have a class which represents the racing car and inside of it i have a method witch prints to the console whenever a car passes a 1000 int checkpoint.

inside the run override i call that method and it suppoused to run differently for each car i create, but i think i got something wrong because the results changes every time(it needs to stay the same because some cars are faster, so i dont think the cars are moving in different threads).

```
public class RacingCar extends Thread{
private String model;
private int speed;
public RacingCar(){}
public RacingCar(String model, int speed){
    this.start();
    this.model = model;
    this.speed = speed;
}
public void go(){
    int trackLength=5000;
    int checkPointPassed=0;
    for(int i=0;i<trackLength;i+=speed){
        if(checkPointPassed*1000<i){
            checkPointPassed++;
            System.out.println(this.model+" has passed the "+checkPointPassed+"th check point");
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void run() {
    go();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Tester(main):

```
public class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RacingCar("Honda", 6);
    new RacingCar("Lamborghini", 100);
    new RacingCar("McLaren", 8);
}}
```

Comment: You have no guarantee in what order the threads will execute. What you are doing is creating three threads, letting each of them loop until it reaches 1000 before printing. And then after that, sleep 10ms and exit. You probably meant to set the speeds before starting the threads, as well as sleeping inside the loop (but even then, you will have no strict guarantee of the order of the printlines...).

Comment: Although may be unrelated to the original question, but are you sure about the order: `start(); this.model=model; this.speed = speed;`? Initialisation after action?

Comment: Using one thread per simulated object _seriously_ limits the scalability of your simulation and it probably also makes your simulation more complex.  If you're trying to simulate something in real-time (e.g., for display in a window), then you're probably better off using tasks submitted to a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` or some kind of a GUI framework timer to perform your time-sensitive computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the sleep inside the loop, as well as fully creating the RacingCars before starting the threads.

```
public class RacingCar extends Thread {
    private String model;
    private int speed;

    public RacingCar(String model, int speed) {
        this.model = model;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            go();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void go() throws InterruptedException {
        int trackLength = 5000;
        int checkPointPassed = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < trackLength; i += speed) {
            if(checkPointPassed * 1000 < i) {
                checkPointPassed++;
                System.out.println(this.model + " has passed the " + checkPointPassed + "th check point");
            }
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RacingCar honda = new RacingCar("Honda", 6);
        RacingCar lamborghini = new RacingCar("Lamborghini", 100);
        RacingCar mcLaren = new RacingCar("McLaren", 8);

        honda.start();
        lamborghini.start();
        mcLaren.start();
    }
}
```

(Mind that even when you do this, you have no strict guarantee in which order the threads are scheduled to run.)

Comment: Could you please put the `try` into the body of `run` and make the `run` method return on the `InterruptedException`. It hurts to see code like this, even though it was originally like this.

Comment: I do not want to unwind the thread on interrupt (rather, I do not care in this educational example) -- I just want to convey the essence of the loop to Arie Pinto! :)

Comment: I agree, this is not the main point, but I guess the whole example will be taken adopted, not only the loop. Is it a good practice to teach bad practice?

Comment: No, I do not think that it is good practice to teach bad behaviour -- but I do believe that leaving out as many details as possible can be worthwhile, while developing a basic intuition. (In this case, I do not think that Arie would understand the basic issues with his race loops better by letting the racing car threads behave well under interrupts -- so I decided to move that detail away from the main logic.) That said, examples can always be improved -- so I will implement your suggestion. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Well, here:

```
public RacingCar(String model, int speed){
    this.start();
    this.model = model;
    this.speed = speed;
}
```

you're using `this.start()` before the object is fully created, this is bad.
Second thing, you're assigning the parameters after the thread runs already (means non-deterministic behavior).

In general you should create the object and run it outside of the constructor.

Comment: Wait a sec, the second statement is correct, but what is that about "you're using this before the object is fully created"? The object is created by now as all the super constructors and implicit initialisations are done, it is not fully initialised with the arguments passed into the constructor, but that might be intentional (although erroneous).

Comment: The object is fully constructed once all the constructors are done. Otherwise the behavior is undefined. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=254

Comment: You meant to say that he calls `start` before the object is fully constructed. Then I would agree. But using `this` in the constructor is not a problem per se, e.g. `this.model = model` does not lead to any undefined behaviour. That is what I meant.

Comment: Oh, you're right. That was in my head, forgot to type it in :)